# Is it possible to compute the $\limsup$ of $x_n$ where $x_n$ is the $n^{th}$ digit of $\pi$?

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory

I'm curious about something. Let $x_n$ represent the $n-$th digit of $\pi$ i.e. $\pi=3.1415$ and thus $$x_0=3,\quad  x_1=1,\quad  x_2=4,\quad  x_3=1,...$$

Is it possible to determine $$\liminf_{n\to\infty } x_n\quad \text{and} \quad \limsup_{n\to\infty } x_n\ \ ?$$  I would naturally have think that $$\liminf_{n\to\infty }x_n=0 \quad \text{and}\quad  \limsup_{n\to\infty }x_n=9,$$ but I can't prove it. I tried by contradiction, but without success. Any idea ?

Comment: The sequence $\{x_n\}$ is random in its true sense. So it should have no such limits.

Comment: Of course your conjecture is equivalent to saying that there are infinitely many $0$'s and infinitely many $9$'s in the decimal expansion. And of course that "must" be true. Sticking my neck way out, my _guess_ is that nobody knows how to prove it. We'll see if anyone explains that I'm being stupid again...

Comment: Noone knows for any digit $d=0-9$, whether $d$ appears infinite many often in the decimal representation of $\pi$. It is widely believed that every digit appears infinite many often (even more : $\pi$ is normal), but this belief could well be false.

Comment: @SchrodingersCat The sequence is certainly not random! And he wasn't asking about limits, but about the $\limsup$ and $\liminf$; _any_ sequence has a $\limsup$ and a $\liminf$.

Comment: A computable number is never random if the definition for random is that usually used. $\pi$ seems to behave like a random-digit-generator, but since all digits can be calculated (in principle) with a finite program, $\pi$ cannot be a random number.

Comment: not directly related to your question, but the $\limsup x_n^{1/n}$ does exist and equals $1$

Answer (score 4):

This is a very difficult question, and currently nothing more can be said than $$\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty} x_n\geq 1$$ and $$\liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty} x_n\leq 8.$$

It's possible that beyond some point all of the digits of $\pi$ are $0$'s and $1$'s, and it's also possible that beyond some point all of the digits are $8$'s and $9$'s. We cannot disprove either of these cases. However all $0$'s is not possible since $\pi$ is irrational, and similarly for all $9$'s, which is why we get the above very weak bounds.

This is related to whether or not $\pi$ is a [normal number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_number), and you will find a complete answer explaining the current state of knowledge on this Math Overflow question: [What is the state of our ignorance about the normality of pi?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/51853/what-is-the-state-of-our-ignorance-about-the-normality-of-pi).